# Identify a TV show with woman who grows hair and attacks man on beach

Tags: movie, story-identification

I very vaguely remember part of a TV show around 1980-1982.  In it a lady had some medical treatment, then went on the beach.  She promptly grew a huge amount of hair all over her body so she looked like a Yeti-type creature.  Then she attacked a man on the beach.  I was terrified.  I think it was a TV show because there was a logo at the beginning and end of the adverts.  It was an animal face I believe.  Please help me find what it is.

Comment: Where were you when you saw this? Britain, Australia, Canada, the USA?

Comment: Sorry - it was the UK, Central region of ITV